# What is a negative way to describe a person who is overindulged with Earthly life?

Tags: single-word-requests

To the extent that the person becomes neglectful of all else, including ethics, rights, etc.?

Example: Those who are [word] are so indulged in satisfying their whims and desires that they forget that death shall soon arrive, separating them from all they acquired and delivering them to a stage of reckoning and justice for all the injustice and cruelty they committed.

Comment: OP your use of "Earthly" is unusual and does not jibe with your use of "ethics" and "rights".  Now it may mean something to your religious teachers, but it's not a *common* use.  Could you possibly [edit] to rephrase more clearly please?

Comment: As opposed to what? Some will argue that the world is all there is, so this concept doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Downvoted because it proceeds from the assumption of particular religious beliefs, e.g. that it's possible to overindulge &c, making it more suited for the site of your particular religion.

Comment: Is this more about being concerned with earthly desires than an afterlife or about fulfilling desires at the expense of other people? Your example sentence implies both, but there could be different words depending on which part you wish to emphasize. Your example also doesn't really need your requested word at all. It reads more like a definition than an example usage.

Answer (score 40):

My first thought was ***[Hedonist](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hedonist)***. Oxford (linked on the word) gives the definition as “*A person who believes that the pursuit of pleasure is the most important thing in life; a pleasure-seeker*”, which doesn’t include the implications of *ignoring* or *neglecting* things beyond pleasure, but is nevertheless generally perceived as negative.

Comment: What is the difference between a hedonist and sybarite?

Comment: @hossein - You might want to consider [putting that question to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+hedonist+and+sybarite) and getting an answer first-hand rather than relying on my interpretation.

Comment: @hossein -- The difference is hedonist is used much more than sybarite. Consider your audience, less people will know the word sybarite than hedonist.

Comment: But hedonist and sybarite are both rather positive, IMHO :-)

Comment: @jamesqf, I have heard the term "hedonism" used in contexts that imply selfishness. The term itself does not pass judgement, but people view hedonism through the lens of their own moral worldview. Some people believe everyone should enjoy life as much as possible. Other people believe that self-restraint and a simple lifestyle is better. Depending on your own world view, hedonism could range from very good, to very bad.

Comment: @Kyle A: Yes, that's what I was trying to say.  Whether you view hedonism, or any of the other possibilities, is seen as positive or negative is entirely dependent on your personal, subjective world view.  (And FWIW, I personally view my self-restraint and simple lifestyle as rather hedonistic, since it has cost me rather a  good bit of effort and money to achieve.)

Comment: Or try: "wild-_screaming_-hedonist".

Answer (score 25):

One option is: **decadent**.

One of [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decadent)'s definitions is:

> Luxuriously self-indulgent

which seems to cover the intended meaning well.

Comment: Wiktionary is not a proper dictionary; people who run it have no idea what they are doing. The best ones out there are of the sorts of Oxford and Cambridge (which don’t confirm your definition); or at least Merriam-Webster (that confirms your definition).

Comment: @William the OED definition is woefully out of date. Decadent used to mean self-indulgent, wasteful, or excessively luxurious is common in English. Wiktionary is updated much more rapidly than the OED, which is one reason it's not banned from use on this site as a reference.

Comment: @barbecue Just because it’s not banned, it doesn’t mean it’s good by any standard. And updating quickly according to what? If it’s not registered in a proper dictionary, it’s most likely not how you use the word, otherwise we’re justifying absurd stuff people say in the new world such as “djuuude like I just like literaly left the gym”. There’s a plethora of examples on wiktionary that’ll show you that it’s as trustworthy of a source on English as an ESL on B1 level.

Comment: Anyhow, the word OP is looking for is “hedonist” or “debauchery”, the proper meaning of “decadent” is “one that’s currently decaying”, as it’s the present participle of the verb to “decadere” (to decay).

Comment: The audience of this text is the general people, with different backgrounds. I think it's best to stay safe from using words with so many varying opinions about it.

Comment: @hossein Just so you know, nobody except William is complaining about this word (I can see the downvotes and nobody downvoted this answer (William would've probably if he was allowed)). Not saying that makes it a good fit for your example sentence, but the meaning described in this answer is definitely used in normal english. If you go [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/decadent) and click "more example sentences" you can find a bunch of examples.

Comment: @William I have literally never heard the word "decadent" used with the "proper meaning", then. I have always heard it defined according to this answer. The meaning of the word has likely drifted from the original Latin.

Comment: ‘Decadent’ CAN, absolutely, mean ‘self-indulgent’, since a person who is self indulgent is in a state of moral decay. So ‘decadent’ conotes that meaning, but the proper meaning of a word is its denotation. Besides, normal doesn’t mean correct. And appeals to ignorance are not valid reasoning; differently from the anglosphere, Romance uses the word properly and doesn’t wear illiteracy as a badge of honor.

Comment: @William English dictionaries are descriptive, not proscriptive. If a word in English is used to mean something, that's what it means. We aren't like the French, where there's a group of academics that formally approve all word meanings.

Comment: @user379640 no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Anyone who doubts that the word "decadent" can be used to mean self-indulgent has clearly never looked at a dessert menu.

Answer (score 21):

One possible word not already given in comments is

> **debauched**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Indulging in or characterized by excessive indulgence in sex, alcohol, or drugs.
>   *The result is a debased, debauched culture which finds moral depravity entertaining and virtue contemptible.*

This word perhaps suits the *value judgement* inherent in the question.

> Those who are **debauched** are so indulged in satisfying their whims and desires that they forget that death shall soon arrive, separating them from all they acquired and delivering them to a stage of reckoning and justice for all the injustice and cruelty they committed.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/debauched).

---

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debauched) has a broader definition:

> **debauch**
>   transitive verb
>   **1a** : to corrupt by intemperance or sensuality
>   **1b** : to lead away from virtue or excellence

Comment: I don't think this fits the definition. "Debauchery" is mainly used in contexts where the sheer *excess* of the self-indulgence is looked down upon. In these contexts, the excesses are usually also closely linked to great wealth and expenditure, to the point that I've never seen a poor person being accused of debauchery. Debauchery also does not necessarily imply an abandonment of spiritual concerns, which is what I believe OP is mostly looking for.

Comment: @detuur sex and drugs and rock 'n' roll are available to anyone, they are not just the province of the wealthy.

Comment: @detuur: OP asked for  a _general_ word that _can be used_ in the context of spiritual vs. natural concerns. That is, unless you say that right and ethics depend on religión. And even the simple things in life provide the opportunity to over-indulge an appetite, by a variety of criteria-not only spiritual.

Comment: @detuur also, the Merriam-Webster definition I posted includes: *to lead away from virtue or excellence*.

Answer (score 8):

Try *sybarite* (n) or *sybaritic* (adj).

> **sybarite** *n*
>   1. A person devoted to pleasure and luxury; a voluptuary.
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sybarite)</sub>

The word comes from Sybaris, a city of ancient Greece, which, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybaris), "amassed great wealth thanks to its fertile land and busy port. Its inhabitants became famous among the Greeks for their hedonism, feasts, and excesses, to the extent that "sybarite" and "sybaritic" have become bywords for opulence, luxury and outrageous pleasure-seeking."

Answer (score 6):

> Those who are [word] are so indulged in satisfying their whims and desires that they forget that *death* shall soon arrive...

I think the word you're looking for is *worldly*.

**[Worldly](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/worldly)** **(adj):** relating to or consisting of physical things and ordinary life rather than spiritual things.

**[Worldly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/worldly) (adj):** worldly is used to describe things relating to the ordinary activities of life, rather than to spiritual things.

Comment: Worldly is usually not a negative but a positive. Meaning experienced, or sophisticated.

Comment: @PonderStibbons It's a negative in this context. I've definitely heard it being used this way in Christian circles, and everybody understood that it wasn't a good thing.

Comment: I guessed that, but it feels like a minority usage - just saying. I mean other than in a spiritual context, where I would consider it to be Jargon, it is typically intended in a positive manner. And so, would not satisfy the OPs requirements.

Comment: OP's question is closely related to religious concepts (spirituality) and so is worldly.

Comment: Yes, my question happens to be related to spirituality, but the audience is the general people, who might not be reading the text with spirituality in mind.

Comment: "Worldly" used to be my go-to word for this, but I've learned that other people use it as a compliment. It's not unambiguous. I don't know which is more common among all speakers.

Answer (score 5):

How about "carnal"?

Carnal literally means "of the flesh" and has considerable emotional baggage associated with it. "Sybaritic" is more accurate, being broader in scope, but is less accessible to the unwashed masses. It is also less negative in connotation.

A second reading of the question suggests that the intended sense is that the subject has overdone it. Therefore, I propose "jaded". This is a bit mild; were I to deride someone I would probably say *jaded sybarite wallowing in carnal decadence.*

> The Spartan and Sybarite
> Battle in me day and night;
> Evenly matched, relentless, wary, 
> Each one cursing his adversary,
>     <sub>— *Conflict*, Sara Teasdale (with delighted thanks to Conrado)</sub>

Comment: "The Spartan and Sybarite
Battle in me day and night;
Evenly matched, relentless, wary,
Each one cursing his adversary,..." *Conflict*, Sara Teasdale.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one in its verb form, with a collection of synonyms from [thesaurus.net](https://www.thesaurus.net/sated).

> **sate** (verb) gorge, glut, cloy, stuff, overfill, satiate, surfeit, satisfy, gratify.

It is, perhaps, a bit distorted from its etymological roots, as [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sate#etymonline_v_22760) says that

> **sate** (v.)
>
> "to satisfy, surfeit," c. 1600, alteration (by influence of
>   Latin satiare "satiate"

comes from a root that means simply "fill", without necessarily *over*filling.
However, it is a fine line. I know from experiences that the difference Is only one doughnut.

Here are a few corresponding adjectives:
***sated***, gorged, glutted, surfeited.

Answer (score 1):

That person would be said to be a **Sardanapalus**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardanapalus

Sardanapalus was a king who over indulged in earthly delights and died in an orgy.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Nice first post which could be improved by a brief summary of the content of the link (links don't last forever).

Answer (score 0):

**Temporal** is the word that you seek because it delivers the meaning that you intend without having a familiar positive meaning attached to it, like the word *worldly*.

This word is also much more accurate than all the words that focus on pleasure because you do *not* need to be a hedonist in order to be temporal!

Think about it: You can be perfectly hardworking yet feverishly attached just to this world, its tangible, materialistic benefits and results. You can work so hard to accumulate as much money and gold as possible for this world, thus being temporal, without really having any significant amount of fun with that money.

In short, you can be a hardworking, stoic secularist; you can be temporal and allergic to pleasure, or temporal *and* hedonistic.

**temporal** (adj.)

- of or relating to time.
- pertaining to or concerned with the present life or this world; worldly:
  temporal joys.
- enduring for a time only; temporary; transitory (opposed to eternal).
- secular, lay, or civil, as opposed to ecclesiastical.